# Looking for a word meaning "On the left or right, or both (left and right)"

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word meaning
"On the left or right, or both (left and right)"

Example:

> I will have people on my left or right, or both left and right.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange ELU! Single word requests require more detail. What is the context in which this word will be used? Can you give one or more examples of this word in use? What research have you done yourself to find this word? Have you found any that are similar but not quite right? If so, what are they and why did they not work for you?

Comment: I too think that context is required. Perhaps you could use "I will have people at my side."

Comment: @michael.hor257k I suppose that does work, but I'd like to be a bit more specific than that.

Comment: "I will have people by my sides"?

Comment: @MarkHubbard "I may have people on either side" ? - maybe?

Comment: @sudoman "I may have people on either side of me" would be more precise.

Comment: "*I'd like to be a bit more specific than that.*" That doesn't mean anything.Please edit your question and explain in detail what you're trying to say, to whom, in what context, etc.

Comment: @sudoman Michael makes a good point. How will you use this sentence? For instance, "I want someone to take a photograph of me, but I may have people on either side of me." Can you supply more examples that would help us to be more helpful to you?

Comment: I will have people beside me.

Comment: If you happen to be talking about politics, you need to say that you're referring to politics.  A common way of describing a person between the left and the right is a "centrist". However, that no longer works in the current political reality as you have a third access of globalist/tradionionalist to cope with.

Comment: 'alignment' classifies things along an access.  Like you could have text left aligned, right aligned or center aligned?

Comment: are you looking for a term that means 3 choices  either/or/both ?  I'd like to know a word for that.

Comment: 'I will have people alongside.' But I'd stick with 'I will have people beside me'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A word that fits your description is ***flanking***. It is the present participle of the verb *[flank](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flank)*:

> to be situated at the side of; especially:  to be situated on both sides of

Examples:

- “This view is a combination of nature and artifice; the house is angled for it, the unbroken lawn leads to it, the **flanking** tree plantations frame it, [...]” (George Seddon, *Landprints: Reflections on Place and Landscape*)
- “They form small courtyards, each consisting of a main building and **flanking** buildings.” (Qinghua Guo, *The Mingqi Pottery Buildings of Han Dynasty China, 206 BC-AD 220*)

Comment: So would then sentence then be: "I have people flanking around me"?

Comment: @sudoman "There are people flanking me" or "People are flanking me". Note that the word *flank* can have military connotations; make sure your context is clear.

Answer (score 0):

J. Siebeneichler has given a good answer, but I will offer a few other comments, I am still not quite sure what situation the original question was asking about.

Typically, when describing having people on various sides of yourself, you would say one of the following.

*There are people all around me.*

*There are people surrounding me.*

*There are people encircling me.*

*There are people on both sides of me.*

*There are people on either side of me.*  --or--
*There are people to either side of me.*  --or--
*There are people at either side of me.*

*There are people in front of and behind me.*  --or--
*There are people both in front of and behind me.*

*There are people flanking me.*

**all around**  means on all sides (front, back, left, right)

**surrounding**  also means on all sides, but it carries a bit of an implication that there is little or no empty space (there are no gaps) between those people

**encircling** means forming a circle around; used less commonly; to a certain degree, it often implies that the people are intentionally forming a circle

**on either side of** usually means on the left and right

**to either side of** same as on either side of (to either side of is not used much in contemporary American English)

**at either side of** same as on either side, but less common

**flanking** also means on the left and on the right, but it is used less commonly. In informal English, it is much more common to say or write "**I have people on both sides of me**" than to say "I have people flanking me."